# Custom Android battery icon while phone is charging

Tags: android, icons, android-animation

I want to make an application with battery icon when phone is charging. But I don't know where to start. Can you please help me with some ideas?

Later clarification: I would actually like to implement just the animation similar to the one when the battery is charging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an animated icon then you should probably create a [widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html), you can create one that is similar to an icon but that can be animated when the battery is charging.

For the animation you can use the link posted on the comment of Thomas K.

Comment: Thank you for your tips about the animation. I marked your answer but Thomas K helped me also.

Comment: He helped me too, so I +1'd him :)

Answer (score 2):

Afaik this has something to do with your Launcher and it's theme. (correct me if I'm wrong)

See

- [Android: How to create a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603427/android-how-to-create-a-launcher)
- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html
- [How to make a launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher)

Comment: I would actually like to implement just the animation similar to the one when the battery is charging.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html That should do it

Comment: Thanks that worked for me and also this example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216616/animation-in-status-bar-in-android) helped me. I didn't know how to do the animation didn't think this could be so simple.